# Can I initiate a MacOS restart to Recovery mode solely from the command line?

Tags: macos

I've done some searching online without luck, hoping that one of you Mac virtuosos might know the answer. On Intel Macs, I know I can hold <kbd>Command</kbd>  + <kbd>R</kbd> but I'm looking for a terminal command to initiate this without keys being pressed.

Is there a command that will reboot a Mac into recovery mode?

Comment: I just tried:
<br>
`>sudo nvram internet-recovery-mode=RecoveryModeNetwork`
<br>
`>sudo nvram internet-recovery-mode=RecoveryModeDisk`
<br> within Big Sur 11.6 on VirtualBox 6.1.28 and none of them worked. Seems that at reboot nvram vars are just ignored and Guest OS skip booting in Recovery Mode.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can do that using the following command:

```
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"
sudo reboot
```

This sets a firmware variable in **nvram** indicating that you want to start in Recovery mode on the next boot, and then reboots the machine.

When done in Recovery mode, run the following from the Terminal in Recovery mode:

```
nvram -d recovery-boot-mode
```

This deletes the firmware variable so that the next boot is a normal boot.

If Recovery boot fails and you cannot progress, you could also remove the firmware variable by holding down the keys **Command, Option, P, and R** during boot. This resets the **nvram** and thus the firmware variable.

Comment: That worked, `sudo nvram recovery-boot-mode=unused` and `sudo reboot` does indeed boot to recovery. I did not run `sudo nvram -d recovery-boot-mode` to reset nvram, I just simply rebooted the machine and it put me back into the OS.

Comment: This worked for me on an Early 2009 iMac running 10.11!

Comment: Will not work on a 2023 Mac mini without first turning off SIP while in Recovery mode for each attempt, or leaving SIP disabled permanently.

Answer (score 16):

None of the above solutions worked for me in Big Sur.  But this one did.

**Internet:**

```
sudo nvram internet-recovery-mode=RecoveryModeNetwork
```

or **Disk:**

```
sudo nvram internet-recovery-mode=RecoveryModeDisk
```

when done

```
sudo nvram -d internet-recovery-mode
```

Comment: It appears BigSur+ versions need this method.

Comment: Does this method work for Mojave and Catalina?

Comment: Worked on macOS 12.0.1 Monterey.
Note that you'll need the firmware password if there is one. I didn't have it for my work laptop, but after turning it off, it booted into the login screen normally the next time.

Comment: I run `sudo nvram internet-recovery-mode=RecoveryModeDisk` and then `sudo reboot` and my system does not reboot in recovery mode. Am I missing something? I'm trying to get a VirtualBox MacOSX Big Sur to reboot in recovery mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have tried all provided solutions without success on M1 mac mini (Big Sur 11.0)

Ended up with those two steps:

- Power off mac
- Press and Hold Power button until you see Apple logo with options

This is not direct answer but only one worked way to get into recovery that worked for me

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I tried Command R, Command shift R, Command Option R, internet recovery, bmike's answer, and jkosegaard's answer. None worked except this

Answer (score 4):

Yes - along with the Big Sur and the Intel / M1 chip changes introduced by Apple, I'm using this tool to manage this (and other things) for me.

- [Booting to macOS Recovery and Diagnostics Mode](https://twocanoes.com/booting-to-macos-recovery-and-diagnostics-mode/)

This is open source, so you can look at how it works under the hood for each iteration of the OS and various `nvram` settings.

Not all invocations work on all OS and hardware: For example, on my Mac Pro 2013 (the shiny black cylinder Mac Pro) the only command that worked for me was

```
sudo nvram internet-recovery-mode=RecoveryModeDisk
sudo reboot
```

Now that Big Sur and the Apple Silicon M1-based Macs have shipped - we can retest this on the 2020 hardware.

- [Internet Recovery, Recovery Partition or HW Diag from macOS](https://mrmacintosh.com/boot-to-internet-recovery-recovery-partition-or-diagnostics-from-macos/)
- [Mac startup key combinations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)

Comment: Would you happen to know how to choose which macOS Recovery partition to boot to? See [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430390/recovery-mode-not-seeing-all-apfs-snapshots) question for more context.

Comment: I reopened that question, but it will need more information (I believe) to be answerable - but who knows if someone else knows more than I @sunknudsen

Answer (score 0):

That was working fine for me up to High Sierra. From Mojave and beyond I get a slashed circle symbol indicating that's no recovery partition, so I have to manually do <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>.

Answer (score -3):

Here is an app that lets you to boot into anywhere.

https://twocanoes.com/booting-to-macos-recovery-and-diagnostics-mode/

Comment: This has already been suggested, with considerably more detail.