# Mac Mini 2018 (w/T2) Ignores Cmd-R, Option, and anything else on reboot

Tags: keyboard, startup, mac-mini

I have a 2018-era Mac Mini (Macmini8,1) running Catalina 10.15.7.

I am unable to get the system to recognize any commands I hold down during system reset. I have tried both my existing wireless keyboard (Microsoft with a USB dongle) and a plug-in USB keyboard. Regardless, if I hold down `Option` during boot, I get no menu. If I hold down `Command-R`, I get no Recovery mode. If I hold down `Command-Option-P-R` I do not get the behavior that indicates the NVRAM has been zapped. In all cases, I boot directly into the normal OS and log-in screen.

I did try the [command line technique](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367336/macos-boot-to-recovery-mode-command-line), but this did not solve the problem I'm after, as it's not possible to adjust the System Security Tools when you do it this way. :-(

Advice welcome--thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try an Apple keyboard.

One of my Mac Pros has a Logitech Windows keyboard, which it completely ignores if I want to do diagnostics. I have to use one of the Apple keyboards to get it to listen.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem, more or less. Two other keyboards didn't properly map the Command key. In the end, I found a third USB-wired keyboard that worked (not from Apple, but on which the WIndows key = Command key for Mac).  So, if you're having this problem in the future: try lots of different keyboards.