# How to reboot into recovery mode in Catalina with command line?

Tags: macos, catalina, recovery

I am trying to boot into recovery mode from the command line.
The following commands (from [Can I initiate a MacOS restart to Recovery mode solely from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367336/can-i-initiate-a-macos-restart-to-recovery-mode-solely-from-the-command-line)) didn't work for me:

- `sudo nvram recovery-boot-mode=unused`
- `sudo nvram internet-recovery-mode=RecoveryModeNetwork`
- `sudo nvram internet-recovery-mode=RecoveryModeDisk`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I initiate a MacOS restart to Recovery mode solely from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367336/can-i-initiate-a-macos-restart-to-recovery-mode-solely-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @X_841 no, this commands dont work for me

Comment: you don't mention the keyword `sudo` in your question. Did you do that?

Comment: @X_841 yes, of course. I ran commands under sudo

Comment: Then I can't help you, sry.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Does setting the value gives an error, does the system reboot normally if you trigger a reboot afterwards, or something else?

Comment: @nohillside system reboots as usuall

Comment: On an **Intel** based **Mac**, I use the following _compound command_ on a single line in **Terminal**, while running **macOS Catalina** normally, to boot to **macOS Recovery** and it works for me without issue: `sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"; sleep 2; sudo reboot`