# How to remove glitched macOS Big Sur Installer?

Tags: macos, install

I'm perpetually stuck on macOS 11.0 beta (the last one) because a glitched installer for 11.0.1 RC1 is stuck on my system.

I can't remove it, and I have to option-boot out of the installer every time I turn on my Mac. I even looked at Disk Utility, and there's a 30GB partition called `com.apple.os.update-1F1A...` which seems to contain the installer, which doesn't seem to be removable.

Can anyone help me out with next steps? I'd like to be able to install updates again (or at least my free space back)

[image: Option-booting out of installer]
[image: Disk Utility]

Comment: I'd be happy to provide any additional information (within reason) needed to get rid of this, but I'm truly stumped here...

Comment: ive got the same issue on a non beta big sur installation. i just thought it was some new undocumented bs partition from apple again.

Comment: Have you tried [disabling SIP](https://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/) and then deleting it?

Comment: You likely need to look around the APFS container with the command line. Start with `diskutil apfs list` and see if you find the `com.apple.os.update-1F1A...` volume.

Comment: I assumed you are unable to remove it because of SIP. I would try disabling SIP, booting into Recovery and opening `Disk Utility` from it and then try deleting the installer partition. BTW, please share more details - how did you actually try to remove the installer partition, and details of any error you got?

Comment: @sfxedit The issue is that I'm not sure how to boot into Recovery when I have to Option-boot every time I want to use the computer to get out of the glitched installer. Can I make the installer second in the list so I can get to Recovery? I can't enable SIP without being in Recovery mode.

Comment: Boot with option-boot. Open Apple menu and go to *System Preferences > Startup Disk*. Unlock it and select your working macOS disk and click **Restart**. Again option-boot if it doesn't boot normally. Open terminal and follow the instructions in this answer - [boot into recovery mode using command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367367/333666). Once in recovery mode, open Terminal (Utility > Terminal), and disable SIP with command `csrutil disable` and restart. Again, boot into Recovery mode. Now open Disk Utility and delete the macOS installer. Hopefully everything should work fine.

Comment: @sfxedit After taking a backup, I went into Internet Recovery mode and wiped Macintosh HD. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m reposting my comment from 2021-05-25T00:35Z as an answer:

> After taking a backup, I went into Internet Recovery mode and wiped Macintosh HD. Thank you for your help!