# How to disable SIP when Big Sur or later macOS is installed in a VMware Fusion Player virtual machine

Tags: macos, virtualization, efi, vmware, firmware

I have Big Sur installed in a VMware Fusion Player virtual machine. I desire to disable SIP. With an actual physical Mac, the usual method would involve first booting to internal macOS Recovery, then entering the command given below in a Terminal window.

```
csrutil disable
```

However, booting to internal macOS Recovery does not seem possible. The holding down the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combination at startup does not work. The Mac Startup Manager does not appear to exist. I can restart to firmware, but the `Recovery` volume does not have a `boot.efi` which can be chosen to boot from.

I realize the SIP setting is stored in the 4 byte NVRAM variable given below.

```
7C436110-AB2A-4BBB-A880-FE41995C9F82:csr-active-config
```

The firmware does allow booting to a built‑in EFI 1.0 shell. However, this shell does not appear to have any commands which can modify this variable. In fact, the variable does not even currently exist in the virtual machine NVRAM. I tried entering the command below in a macOS Terminal window.

```
 sudo nvram csr-active-config=%7f%00%00%00
```

The result was the error message given below.

```
nvram: Error setting variable - 'csr-active-config': (iokit/common) not permitted
```

**What procedures can be used used to disable SIP?**

I am using the current free version of VMware Fusion Player (Version 12.1.0).

| **Host Stats** | **Guest Stats** |
| --- | --- |
| iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013) | Mac |
| macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 | macOS Big Sur version 11.6.1 |
| Memory: 16 GB | Memory: 4 GB |
| Quad-Core Intel Core i5 | 2 processor cores |
| 2.9 GHz | 2.76 GHz |
| USB 3 (5 Gb/s) Samsung T7 SSD | SATA HDD |

Below are a links to sites with procedures that either I could not get to work or only work with previous versions of macOS.

[Can I initiate a MacOS restart to Recovery mode solely from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367336/can-i-initiate-a-macos-restart-to-recovery-mode-solely-from-the-command-line)
[how to disable SIP (system integrity protection) in vmware fusion 12 for macOS big sur?](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/how-to-disable-SIP-system-integrity-protection-in-vmware-fusion/td-p/2313906)

Comment: I don't have VMware so I can't try it out, but have you looked at the answer in: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/how-to-disable-SIP-system-integrity-protection-in-vmware-fusion/td-p/2313906

Comment: The problem with the linked answer you provide is there is no `boot.efi` file. I posted this in my question. The the previous versions of macOS have this `boot.efi` file, but not Big Sur.

Comment: Sorry, here's another thing you could try: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Can-t-boot-into-recovery-partition-on-macOS-11-Big-Sur/m-p/2819457/highlight/true#M171572

Comment: I was aware of this link. Basically, you create a macOS installer on either a virtual USB drive of virtual optical media. Next, boot from the drive or media and open a Terminal window where the `csrutil disable` command can be entered. The procedure for creating both the drive and media is complex and the time needed to boot is fairly long. I was hoping for something simpler and faster. You can post as an answer, but I would consider this to be a answer of last resort.

Comment: **VMware Fusion** has to create a temporary installer on a second vHDD and I always make a copy of the initial installer and VM by selecting Customize so it doesn't immediately start the install.  Then later this installer vHDD can be added back to the VM so as to access **macOS Recovery** when needed.

Comment: Up until this point I had no reason to go into **macOS Recovery** from a **macOS Big Sur** VM. In previous releases of **macOS** I used the _compound command_ `sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"; sleep 2; sudo reboot` from **Terminal** to reboot to **macOS Recovery**. Thanks to your question and very interesting answer, I have now set up a **macOS Recovery** vHDD from the **Temporary Installation Source Disk.vmdk** and **Temporary Installation Source Disk.dmg** _files_ create by **VMware Fusion**.

Comment: I've edited these files so in **Disk Utility** from a normal boot it shows as **macOS Recovery** instead of the original given name. I also added its **UUID** to `/etc/fstab` so it's _read-only_ and does not mount on a normal boot. I've added it as a shared vHDD to utilize it across all of my **macOS Big Sur** VM's and minimize **Host** disk space usage. Not to take away from your interesting answer, but for me this going forward IMO is much better solution for issues like this. (Both booting to **macOS Recovery** and or disabling **SIP**.)

Comment: You should post these comments as an answer. I do not think making a copy of the temporary installation drive would be a solution that most users would think of on their own. Booting to a macOS installer drive is a valid way to disable SIP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Follow the steps below to disable System Integrity Protection (SIP).

1. Start by booting to macOS Big Sur and opening a Terminal application window. Next, enter the command given below. This will create a NVRAM variable with the desired value, but misspelled variable name. This misspelling will be corrected in a later step.

   ```
   sudo nvram Asr-active-config=%7f%00%00%00
   ```
2. Shutdown macOS. In the `Setting` window for the virtual machine, select
   `Startup Disk`. Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and select the `Restart to Firmware…` button, as shown below.

   [image]

   Select the `EFI Internal Shell`, as shown below.

   [image]

   If desired, enter the command below to get full use of the window.

   ```
   mode 128 40
   ```
3. Set the current filesystem to the EFI volume. This should be the mapped `fs0` filesystem, so you would enter the following

   ```
   fs0:
   ```

   Next, verify the label is `EFI` by entering the command below.

   ```
   vol
   ```

   If wrong, then try `fs1:`, `fs2:`, `fs3:`, ....
4. Enter the command below to save the `Asr-active-config` variable to the file `csr.bin`.

   ```
   dmpstore Asr-active-config -s csr.bin
   ```

   > Note: For more information on this command enter `help -b dmpstore`.

   Next, enter the command below to edit the `csr.bin` file. You will need to correct the spelling by replacing the letter `A` with the letter `c`. The can be done by typing a `63` over the `41` on the first line.

   ```
   hexedit csr.bin
   ```

   The corrected file will appear as shown below. When finished save the changes and exit.

   > Note: The value of the variable is stored in the last 4 bytes of this file.

   [image]

   Enter the command below to create the `csr-active-config` variable in NVRAM.

   ```
   dmpstore -l csr.bin
   ```

   SIP will now be disabled on the next boot of Big Sur. If desired, enter the command below to remove the `Asr-active-config` variable from NVRAM.

   ```
   dmpstore -d Asr-active-config
   ```
5. Enter the command below to leave the command shell.

   ```
   exit
   ```

   From the `Boot Manager`, select `Mac OS X` to boot Big Sur.

### Format of the `csr.bin` File

| Offset in Hex | Size in Decimal | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00-03 | 4 | Length of variable name |
| 04-27 | 36 | Variable name stored as null terminated UTF-16LE string |
| 28-37 | 16 | GUID of the variable |
| 38-3B | 4 | Attributes stored as 4 byte integer (See below) |
| 3C-3F | 4 | Length of the data |
| 40-43 | 4 | The 4 byte integer that comprises the data |

| Attribute | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NV | 1 | Non-volatile |
| BS | 2 | Boot service Access |
| RT | 4 | Runtime Access |
| HR | 8 | Hardware Error Record |

Comment: Wow. This is nuts. Why the heck doesn’t VMWare provide an easier way to do this?!

Comment: Does `sudo nvram Asr-active-config=%7f%00%00%00` actually do anything?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy: There is an easier way. You can install an UEFI Shell (v2.2). This shell has a `setvar` command which can modify the NVRAM variables used by macOS. Currently, Fusion Player has a built-in EFI Shell (v1.0). This shell has a `set` command which can only modify environment variables. There is no `setvar` command. BTW, VirtualBox has a built-in UEFI shell (v2.2).

Comment: @Wowfunhappy: The `sudo nvram Asr-active-config=%7f%00%00%00` command causes the variable to be created under a misspelled name. This was necessary, because the Big Sur `nvram` command will not accept the `csr-active-config` name. This misspelling will be corrected once the built-in EFI Shell is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

> While this answer does provide a method for disabling SIP, I consider the method to be overly complicated, if sole purpose is to disable SIP. Also, the time need to boot is longer than booting to an EFI or UEFI shell. However, if there are other tasks that also need to be performed from a macOS Recovery environment, then this method may be preferred over simpler methods.

On a actual Mac, SIP can be disabled by entering the command `csrutil disable` in a Terminal window while booted from a USB flash drive macOS installer. Apple has a [website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) providing the instructions for creating this USB flash drive macOS installer. VMware Fusion Player does not offer virtual USB drives. However, a virtual second internal drive can be substituted. The steps needed to create this virtual drive are given below.

> Note: For the better view of the images, either click on the image or open the image in a new window.

1. ***Aquire the installer application:*** If the `Install macOS Big Sur` application does not already exist in the `Applications` folder on the host, then download the application or transfer a copy from another Mac. This answer assumes the macOS version is 11.6.1.
2. ***Create the installer disk image:*** On the host, open the Disk Utility. From the Disk Utility menu bar, select `File`>`New Image`>`Blank Image…`. In the popup choose the following, the select the `Save` button.

   [image]

   After the disk image creation operation completes successfully, select the `Done` button. Next, open a Terminal application window on the host and enter the command below.

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
   ```

   When finished creating the `Install macOS Big Sur` volume, use the Disk Utility to eject all disk images. Quit the Disk Utility and Terminal applications.
3. ***Set up sharing:*** With the client shutdown, open the `Sharing` pane of the `Settings` for the client. Check off the box labeled `Enable Shared Folders` and add your `Desktop` folder, as shown below.

   [image]
4. ***Create new internal HDD:*** With the client still shutdown, add a new hard disk. Use the settings shown below.

   [image]
5. ***Separate the new HDD from the client:*** This is an optional step which is useful if you what to share the new HDD with other virtual machines.

   > Note: This sharing assumes only one client at a time with be using this drive. Otherwise, this drive should be mounted read-only. (This may be possible by editing the `/etc/fstab` file.

   First, remove the new HDD from the client. When the pop below appears, select the `Keep File` button.

   [image]

   Use the Finder application to move the `Virtual Disk 2.vmdk` file from the client folder to the parent folder named `Virtual Machines`. Next, rename the file to `BigSur11.6.1Installer.vmdk`. Finally, add this new HDD to the client as an existing HDD. When selecting the file, be sure the `Share this virtual disk with the virtual machine that created it` button is selected, as shown below.

   [image]
6. ***Initialize the new HDD:*** Start up the client virtual machine. When the popup below appears, select the `Initialize…` button. The Disk Utility application should open.

   [image]

   Highlight the new uninitialized `VMware Virtual SATA Hard Drive Media` and then select the `Erase` button. Make the selections shown below, then select the `Erase` button.

   [image]

   Quit the Disk Utility.
7. ***Install VMware Tools:*** If VMware Tools is already installed, then skip to the next step. From the `VMware Fusion` menu bar, select `Virtual Machine`>`Install VMware Tools`. Proceed to install. If either of the two windows below requests a `Restart`, do **not** do so.

   [image]

   [image]

   The system software from developer "VMware, Inc." will be blocked from loading. You should select the `Allow` button from the `Security & Privacy` pane of System Preferences, when this happens. Afterwards, when the window shown below requests a `Restart`, then you should do so.

   [image]
8. **Restore to the new drive:** From the client, open your `Desktop` folder stored on the host, then open the `BigSur11.6.1Installer.dmg` file. On the client, open the Disk Utility application and highlight the `MyVolume` volume. From the top of the Disk Utility window, select `Restore`. In the popup, select to restore from `Install macOS Big Sur`, then select the `Restore` button.

   > Note: On my Mac, the restore took about 8 minutes.

   When finished, select the `Done` button. From the Disk Utility, eject the Disk image with the `Install macOS Big Sur` volume, then quit the Disk Utility. Close any open Finder windows.
9. ***Cleanup:*** From the host, move the `BigSur11.6.1Installer.dmg` file from your `Desktop` folder to the Trash. If desired, restore Shared Folders to its original state.

To boot from new macOS installer drive, take the following steps.

1. Shutdown the client.
2. From the host, open the `Startup Disk` pane of the `Settings` for the client.
3. Highlight the HDD icon labeled `Hard Disk 2 (SATA)`.
4. Select the `Restart…` button.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative Way to Boot in Recovery Mode with Big Sur

Just to share my tryout after reading first post of David Anderson who helped me to find this.

The environment it's little different from VMW Fusion, actually it is this:

Guest OS: Big Sur 11.6

Host OS: Big Sur 11.6 on MBA 2020 (Intel)

Hypervisor: Virtual Box 6.1.28

I have tried every way to boot in Recovery Mode, either using nvram, or through EFI Internal Shell, all with no success (within my environment).

- `sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"`  ==> With this old (Catalina) var, I even get “Error setting variable” in Big Sur.
- `sudo nvram internet-recovery-mode=RecoveryModeDisk` ==> when rebooting GuestOS, seems variable to be ignored as MBA don't actually boot in Recovery Mode.
- `dmpstore -l csr.bin` ==> returns “No matching variable found.”

And also booting in EFI Internal Shell and looking for CoreServices/boot.efi, I searched through all FS*N*: mapping table entries (all vols/partitions of local internal Disk of MBA), with no success. It seems System/Library/CoreServices is hidden or encrypted (SSV?)

Then, as suggested by t0rr3sp3dr0 [here in GitHub](https://github.com/geerlingguy/macos-virtualbox-vm/issues/46), tried to look for CoreServices boot.efi, this way and I did as follow:

- In VirtualBox under VM Settings —> Storage, mount Big Sur Installation image. And check “Live CD/DVD” option.
- Start VM and press ESC key
- Choose Boot Manager —> EFI Internal Shell
- Look for Recovery Partition, in my environment under FS7, type:

  `FS7:`

  `vol`

  to check for HFS+.
- Type:

  `cd System/Library/CoreServices`

  `boot.efi`

  `ENTER`

[image]

Finally, my GuestOS (BigSur 11.6) boots in Recovery Mode!

Hope might help.

Comment: Your answer is for booting an optical version of the macOS Big Sur installer in VirtualBox. My question is how to disable SIP when using VMware. I do not see the relevance of your answer. You might consider posting your own question, then posting this answer to your own question.

Comment: You are aware that VirtualBox does not fully support Big Sur, where as VMware does fully support Big Sur. Also, VMware is now a free product if used for personal purposes. Also, you can have both products installed at the same time.

Comment: In your answer, you first boot to an UEFI Interactive Shell v2.2, then boot from the optical media. Why not just disable SIP while booted to the shell and skip using the optical media? I already posted the instructions back in March. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415086/how-to-disable-sip-when-big-sur-is-installed-in-a-vmware-fusion-player-virtual-m/415521#415521). Since VirtualBox already has a Shell v2.2, rEFInd is not needed.

Comment: Dear DA, many thx for comments and I was simply looking for something really close to your Q&A, as you stated in your question *“but the Recovery volume does not have a boot.efi which can be chosen to boot from.”*. And these are also 2 point I also had: disable SIP and Recovery Boot. And your post are great, they helped me and a lot of other people.

Comment: Only thing I’m managing it with VirtualBox, but main questions are the same. If you prefer, I’ll detach and write a Q&A by myself. When you’re looking for something not all the times you’ll find a specific post for your specific answer, my intention only was to share my little tryout hoping it might help someone.

Yes, I’m aware regarding your comment on VMW. Actually I currently am using VMW Workstation on Windows for lots of years, but I don’t have Fusion on macOS yet, sorry.

Comment: Finally, yes sure I saw [your post of March](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415086/how-to-disable-sip-when-big-sur-is-installed-in-a-vmware-fusion-player-virtual-m/415521#415521) and it worked great!
Just for info, setting this alias in UEFI Shell, and booting into “Mac OS X” I later get from cmdline:
*Guest OS>csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.*

Comment: This is great for disabling SIP, without “Big Sur” bootable image mounted, as you asked. Anyway for future need it miss step to go Recovery Mode Boot, because I could’t find any CoreServices/boot.efi without using external bootable image.

Comment: I was not suggesting you detach your answer from this question. I just thought others could find your answer more easily, if a new question was posted. You could leave this answer here and at the other question. Or, leave a brief answer at one question with a link to this answer posted at the other question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer relies on having first installed an UEFI Shell v2.2. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415149/how-to-invoke-a-uefi-shell-v2-2-on-a-fusion-player-virtual-machine-with-big-su/415484#415484) for instructions on how to use rEFInd to invoke an UEFI shell.

Choose one of two bulleted procedures below to install the `csrutil` UEFI shell alias.

- Enter the command below in a UEFI shell. Since this alias is nonvolatile, the command will only needed to be entered once.

  ```
   alias csrutil "setvar csr-active-config -nv -rt -bs -guid 7C436110-AB2A-4BBB-A880-FE41995C9F82"
  ```
- Install the `startup.nsh` file as described in the [referenced answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415149/how-to-invoke-a-uefi-shell-v2-2-on-a-fusion-player-virtual-machine-with-big-su/415484#415484). This script will create a volatile form of alias shown above each time a UEFI shell is invoked.

To modify the System Integrity Protection configuration, enter the commands in the "UEFI Shell Equivalent" column below in a UEFI shell.

| macOS Command | UEFI Shell Equivalent | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `csrutil clear` | `csrutil =` | Clear the existing configuration. |
| `csrutil disable` | `csrutil =0x0000007f` | Disable the protection on the machine. |
| `csrutil enable` | `csrutil =0x00000010` | Enable the protection on the machine. |
| `csrutil status` | `csrutil` | Display the current configuration. |

> Note: Once the `csr-active-config` variable is set, you can enable/disable SIP directly from rEFInd.

The bits of the `csr-active-config` variable are defined in the `csr.h` file. A version of this file can be found in [opensource.apple.com](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-6153.81.5/bsd/sys/csr.h.auto.html). This [developer.apple.com thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/17452) defines some additional `csrutil` arguments for the `enable` command. The relationship between these bits and select `csrutil` commands and arguments is given in the table below for macOS Big Sur version 11.6.1.

> Note: The table below also applies to macOS Monterey version 12.0.1.

| csrutil commands with optional arguments | csr- active- config | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNTRUSTED_ KEXTS =0x001 | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNRESTRICTED_ FS =0x002 | CSR_ ALLOW_ TASK_ FOR_ PID =0x004 | CSR_ ALLOW_ KERNEL_ DEBUGGER =0x008 | CSR_ ALLOW_ APPLE_ INTERNAL =0x010 | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNRESTRICTED_ DTRACE =0x020 | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNRESTRICTED_ NVRAM =0x040 | CSR_ ALLOW_ DEVICE_ CONFIGURATION =0x080 | CSR_ ALLOW_ ANY_ RECOVERY_ OS =0x100 | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNAPPROVED_ KEXTS =0x200 | CSR_ ALLOW_ EXECUTABLE_ POLICY_ OVERRIDE =0x400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| enable | 0x00000010 |  |  |  |  | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑no‑internal | 0x00000000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without kext | 0x00000019 | ⚫ |  |  | ⚫ | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without fs | 0x00000012 |  | ⚫ |  |  | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without debug | 0x00000014 |  |  | ⚫ |  | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without dtrace | 0x00000030 |  |  |  |  | ⚫ | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without nvram | 0x00000050 |  |  |  |  | ⚫ |  | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |
| disable | 0x0000007F | ⚫ | ⚫ | ⚫ | ⚫ | ⚫ | ⚫ | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |

Comment: how come enable ‑‑without fs
and
enable ‑‑without debug
are the same?
Shouldn't enable ‑‑without debug be 0x00000018?

Comment: @startergo: I updated my answer for macOS 11.6.1. The `csrutil enable --without debug` now results in `car-active-config` being set to `0x00000014`. I changed the table to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I had rage quit a few times. :)

1. In VMWare settings, create a new hard disk of at least 16 GB and attach to the guest macOS VM.
2. Boot the macOS VM and format the new hard disk in the guest macOS VM as JHFS+ (not APFS), which is also known as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)", in GUID format.
3. Download the Install Big Sur/Monterey etc application from the App Store.
4. Create a bootable recovery disk on the disk created in step 2 using the instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) on the new hard disk.
5. Shutdown the guest macOS VM.

   From the VM settings -> Startup Disk -> Highlight the new hard disk from Step 1 and then select the `Restart` button.

   OR

   If using VMWare workstation/Player, access the firmware by spamming the <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> key and change the boot order so the disk created in step 2 is first.

   Then you will be on the installer, select your language then choose terminal and enter `csrutil disable` and will see the confirmation message and BOOM it is turned off and you can shed a few tears of joy and enjoy the ego. :)
6. Restart and enter the firmware using the <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> key and change the boot order back to original settings.

If you are still having issues, I can try and make a video.

Comment: I can not get *"enter the firmware using the R or F12 key"* to work. Would it not be easier to hold down the option key and then select the `Restart to firmware...` button on the Startup Disk pane of Settings?

Comment: Yes choose whatever method works for you to enter the bios…..restart to firmware or power on to firmware etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Lots of VERY complicated answers to this question, but I have a much easier way to do it.

First download a bootable ISO of Big Sur from the internet (there are a number of them on the Internet Archive, do a search). Then in the Virtual Machine Settings CD/DVD (SATA) Hardware settings, set it to be "Connected" and "Connected at power on", and point it to the ISO image you downloaded.

Then with your VM shut down, go to the menu: VM - Power - Power onto Firmware

> Note: If you are using the free version of VMware Fusion Player, then “menu: VM - Power - Power onto Firmware” will not exist. Instead, goto the Startup Disk pane of Settings, hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key, then select the “Restart to Firmware…” button.

Within the firmware, select "Enter Setup"

"Configure Boot Options"

"Change boot order"

then hit enter, and select EFI VMware Virtual SATA CDROM Drive (1.0) and then hit the plus sign to move it to the top.

"Commit changes and exit"

"Exit the Boot Maintenance Manager"

"Shut down the system"

Your VM then should boot into the Recovery environment, and you can disable or enable SIP with Terminal there.

And I've found if while you are in Recovery Mode, and you select the Apple menu "Startup Disk", and set it back to your regular boot image, that there is no need to go back into the the VM firmware settings to unset the DVD boot first option.

But I've found that the BEST thing to do is to leave the CDROM boot option set in the firmware, and leave the ISO in your VMware's folder ready to be easily accessed, and just check (or uncheck) the VM's CD/DVD "Connect at power on" setting whenever you want to boot into Recovery Mode (or not.)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and working way of doing this resembles the answer above -

- Start with a misspelled variable. (Asr-active-config, etc, is fine). It's misspelled and thus not protected by macOS.
- On the host, Edit the NVRAM file directly(!) - this is far easier than going into UEFI shell on the guest, etc. Even vim is fine here, since there is no CRC in the file. The "Asr" will be UTF16, so look for A^@s^@r (null terminators for uint16_t). Change 'A' to 'c' by vim's 'r' function, and immediately write file.
- reboot. done

Comment: How does "On the host, Edit the NVRAM file directly" work in practice? Where is this file stored, how can it be opend in `vi`?

Comment: That'd be in the virtual machines.localized folder or wherever you put the VM - next to the .vmx file will be a .nvram file - that's the one to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case: I created a little tool to facilitate this kind of operation.

You can find it there on GitHub: https://github.com/javerous/vm-config

It should be as simple as doing

```
vm-config change /path/to/vm.vmwarevm --csr-disable
```

to disable SIP.

It's a first version, so it may still have some bugs, but from my own tests, it works smoothly. That being said, you may want to use it only on backuped VM for now.