# Hello people , i have little truble with my recovery menu

Tags: startup, recovery

Common guys... i install my macos big sur img on vmware, and me need enter into recovery menu, but when i trying do it, i press and holding command+r and nothing to hapening .Instead entering into recovery menu , i face to face with follow truble that i capture and add in my youtube channel:
Here my demonstrate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s57U9Y0mUdU
What it is? Help me guys,me need disable csruit into safe mode to be change my screen resolution,
and i cannot use no one methods for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  No worries if you’re a non native speaker. Sometimes I suggest editing a question into shape, but with language issues - let’s give you an easy answer if fixing this is challenging.

Comment: ketchup: I am not sure if your question is about booting to Recovery Mode, disabling SIP or changing the screen resolution. If the question is about disabling SIP, then I can refer you to the question [How to disable SIP when Big Sur is installed in a VMware Fusion Player virtual machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415086/how-to-disable-sip-when-big-sur-is-installed-in-a-vmware-fusion-player-virtual-m).

Comment: Looking at the video - that's VMWare on Windows & therefore off-topic. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSj00.png

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), specifically *Installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware (and most other explicitly unlicensed use of product)*

Comment: my problem common in that ,what i cannot entering into recovery menu in general, because he shows me what I took on video.

Comment: @Tetsujin: How do you know Windows is not running on a Mac? If so, then would  not the question be on-topic?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Why on Earth would anyone try to run MacOS on top of Windows on a Mac?

Comment: @Tetsujin: In the answer I posted, I failed to mention Catalina is installed on an external USB SSD. I did this because Catalina on the internal HDD is incredibly slow. However, Windows on the internal HDD runs much faster. So I suppose if I wanted to run Big Sur in a virtual machine and I did not have an external USB SSD, then I would be better off using Windows as the host.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn’t bother with recovery mode if you are running in a hypervisor. You can change the resolution of the “hardware” with drivers and a configuration file in vmware by editing the vmx file.

Can you ask a follow on question listing your specific version of vmware and your host OS and any non-standard steps you took on that setup if you need further help with your virtualization config. They can be finicky and often we need specific details to solve issues like yours.

Answer (score 2):

I have Big Sur (macOS 11.5.1) installed in a VMware virtual machine. Below is my configuration.

VMware Fusion Player version 12.1.2 (17964953)
Host operating system: Catalina (macOS 10.15.7)
Host machine: Apple iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013)

The initial screen resolution after installing was set to 1024x768 and could not be changed on the Display pane of System Preferences in Big Sur. However, after installing "VMware Tools" in Big Sur, the screen resolution automatically updates when the virtual machine window is resized by using the mouse. I can increase the resolution up to the current resolution of the iMac display. The maximum resolution of the iMac display is 1920x1080.

If installing VMware Tools, does not solve your screen resolution problem, then you might consider updating your question to include the following.

VMware Fusion Player version
Host operating system
Host machine

### Additional Comments

- The VMware virtual firmware does not recognize any of the [Mac startup key combinations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255).
- The closest you can come to booting to Recovery Mode for Big Sur would be to create a virtual bootable installer for macOS Big Sur, then boot from this installer. See [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).
- To disable SIP, see [How to disable SIP when Big Sur is installed in a VMware Fusion Player virtual machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415086/how-to-disable-sip-when-big-sur-is-installed-in-a-vmware-fusion-player-virtual-m).

Comment: i trying install vmware tools on macos, but he show me waring: Could not find component on update server. Contact VMware Support or your system administrator.