# Modify SIP in normally booted system

Tags: macos, command-line, high-sierra, security, sip

I have MacBook Pro (2017) with macOS High Sierra (10.13.6). I have SIP and amfi disabled. I want to enable a part / the majority of SIP (e.g. `csrutil enable --without fs`) without having to reboot into the recovery partition and run the `csrutil` command there.

I tried to modify the nvram variable `csr-active-config` using `nvram csr-active-config="w%01%00%00"`, but it returned an error: `nvram: Error setting variable - 'csr-active-config': (iokit/common) general error`. Modifying the variable name gave successful result:

```
# nvram ccsr-active-config="w%01%00%00"
# nvram ccsr-active-config
ccsr-active-config  w%01%00%00
```

Which indicated that there is still something protecting the SIP configuration even when SIP is completely disabled:

```
# csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

Note that I can change `boot-args` variable with `nvram` because I disabled SIP:

```
# nvram boot-args="amfi_get_out_of_my_way=0x1"
# nvram boot-args
boot-args   amfi_get_out_of_my_way=0x1
```

There is only one relevant log message while setting SIP nvram:

```
ERROR 09:47:22.096544 +0800 kernel  Sandbox: nvram(92857) System Policy: deny(1) nvram-set csr-active-config
```

Is it possible to change SIP configuration to become stricter (not less strict) booting into Recovery OS?

Preferably, the solution can enforce SIP configuration as soon as it's changed. The following logs in Console when I do `chmod -x /bin/ls` make me think it's possible:

```
INFO    11:07:38.852242 +0800   sandboxd    Symbolicator for chmod[94599] is NULL.
ERROR   11:07:38.862934 +0800   sandboxd    Failed to produce a full report for: chmod[94599].
ERROR   11:07:38.863015 +0800   sandboxd    Sandbox: chmod(94599) System Policy: allow file-write-mode /bin/ls
```

Comment: Any change you make will require a restart in order for the change to take effect. So would not this mean the answer to your question would be no?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Maybe? I still think maybe it's possible to change SIP while running the system by loading a kext that does some exploit (of course, itself needs SIP to be disabled for it to work in the first place, so not a security concern)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Mac can be configured so that you can enable a part / the majority of SIP without having to reboot into the recovery partition and run the `csrutil` command there. However, a reboot of macOS will still be necessary for any changes to take effect. This answer proposes one such configuration for use with Intel Macs. Although, adaption for use with Apple Silicon Macs seems theoretically possible.

The csrutil command sets the firmware NVRAM variable `csr-active-config`. The macOS operating system reads this 32 bit integer variable at startup to determine which parts of SIP to enable. Instead of using the `csrutil` command, this answer uses a bash script named `mkcsrfile` to create a `csr.bin` file containing the desired value for the `csr-active-config` variable. The format of this file is defined in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415086/how-to-disable-sip-when-big-sur-is-installed-in-a-vmware-fusion-player-virtual-m/415100#415100). Instead of booting to macOS by default, this answer changes the default to boot an UEFI Shell instead. This shell executes a script stored in the file `startup.nsh`. This script first copies the `csr-active-config` value from the `csr.bin` file to NVRAM, then boots macOS.

The bits of the `csr-active-config` variable are defined in the `csr.h` file. A version of this file can be found in [opensource.apple.com](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-6153.81.5/bsd/sys/csr.h.auto.html). This [developer.apple.com thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/17452) defines some additional `csrutil` arguments for the `enable` command. The relationship between these bits and select `csrutil` commands and arguments is summarized in the table below for macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6.

> Note: The table below can vary between versions of macOS (OS X). For example, the table for Big Sur and Monterey can be found at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415086/how-to-disable-sip-when-big-sur-is-installed-in-a-vmware-fusion-player-virtual-m/415521#415521).

| csrutil commands with optional arguments | csr- active- config | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNTRUSTED_ KEXTS =0x001 | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNRESTRICTED_ FS =0x002 | CSR_ ALLOW_ TASK_ FOR_ PID =0x004 | CSR_ ALLOW_ KERNEL_ DEBUGGER =0x008 | CSR_ ALLOW_ APPLE_ INTERNAL =0x010 | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNRESTRICTED_ DTRACE =0x020 | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNRESTRICTED_ NVRAM =0x040 | CSR_ ALLOW_ DEVICE_ CONFIGURATION =0x080 | CSR_ ALLOW_ ANY_ RECOVERY_ OS =0x100 | CSR_ ALLOW_ UNAPPROVED_ KEXTS =0x200 | CSR_ ALLOW_ EXECUTABLE_ POLICY_ OVERRIDE =0x400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| enable | 0x00000010 |  |  |  |  | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑no‑internal | 0x00000000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without kext | 0x00000011 | ⚫ |  |  |  | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without fs | 0x00000012 |  | ⚫ |  |  | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without debug | 0x00000014 |  |  | ⚫ |  | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without dtrace | 0x00000030 |  |  |  |  | ⚫ | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |  |
| enable ‑‑without nvram | 0x00000050 |  |  |  |  | ⚫ |  | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |
| disable | 0x00000077 | ⚫ | ⚫ | ⚫ |  | ⚫ | ⚫ | ⚫ |  |  |  |  |

### Examples of Use

Once the Mac is configured, the `mkcsrfile` command can be used from macOS. Some examples are given below.

- Enable except for fs and internal.

  The `csr-active-config` variable needs to be set `0x00000012`, which can be done from macOS Recovery by using the command shown below.

  ```
   csrutil enable --without fs
  ```

  This answer offers the following command, which can be entered from macOS, as one possible replacement for the above command.

  ```
   mkcsrfile 0x12
  ```
- Enable except for fs, debug, dtrace and internal.

  The `csr-active-config` variable needs to be set `0x00000036`, which can be done from macOS Recovery by using the command shown below.

  ```
   csrutil enable --without fs --without debug --without dtrace
  ```

  Any one of the following commands, which can be entered from macOS, could be used to replace the above command. The first command shown below has three arguments which will be ORed together bitwise by the `mkcsrfile` script.

  ```
   mkcsrfile 0x12 0x14 0x30
  ```

  Instead, a single argument can be used, where the bitwise OR operations are explicitly entered. This shown in the command below.

  ```
   mkcsrfile "0x12|0x14|0x30"
  ```

  Finally, you could perform the bitwise OR operations yourself and just enter the result, as shown below.

  ```
   mkcsrfile 0x36
  ```
- Enable except for fs, debug and dtrace.

  The `csr-active-config` variable needs to be set `0x00000026`, which can be done from macOS Recovery by using the command shown below.

  > Note: The `--no-internal` option sets the `CSR_ALLOW_APPLE_INTERNAL` (`0x10`) bit to zero.

  ```
   csrutil enable --no-internal --without fs --without debug --without dtrace
  ```

  Any one of the following commands, which can be entered from macOS, could be used to replace the above command. The first command shown below has three arguments which will be ORed together bitwise by the `mkcsrfile` script. Here, each argument has the `CSR_ALLOW_APPLE_INTERNAL` (`0x10`) bit set to zero,

  ```
   mkcsrfile 2 4 0x20
  ```

  Instead, a single argument can be used, where the bitwise operations are explicitly entered. This shown in the command below.

  ```
   mkcsrfile "~10&(0x12|0x14|0x30)"
  ```

  Finally, you could perform the bitwise operations yourself and just enter the result, as shown below.

  ```
   mkcsrfile 0x26
  ```

### Steps to Configure an Intel Mac

1. Download an UEFI Shell v1.

   The Arch Linux wiki web site section [Obtaining UEFI Shell](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Obtaining_UEFI_Shell) provides a link to [Precompiled UEFI Shell v1 binaries](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/UDK2018/EdkShellBinPkg) from TianoCore. Since you have a Intel-based Mac, you will need to download the [X64 version](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/UDK2018/EdkShellBinPkg/FullShell/X64) of the `Shell_Full.efi` file to your `Downloads` folder.

   > Note: If any user can confirm that the [Arm version](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/UDK2018/EdkShellBinPkg/FullShell/Arm) works on a Mac with Apple silicon, then post a comment so this answer can be updated.
2. Install UEFI Shell binary and startup script files to the EFI partition.

   Create a file containing the UEFI shell script shown below. Save as `startup.nsh`  in your `Downloads` folder.

   ```
   @echo -off
   set -v uuid E43602C1-8CFF-4F74-AEC7-98E645C7BBEE
   set -v file csr.bin
   if "%StartupDelay%" == "" then
       set StartupDelay 0
   endif
   set -v found nothing
   for %a in "" 1 2 3 4 5 6
     for %b in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
       if not %found% == boot then
         if exist fs%a%b:\%uuid%\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi then
           alias -v macos fs%a%b:\%uuid%\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi
           if %found% == startup then
             goto BREAK
           endif
           set -v found boot
         endif
       endif
       if not %found% == startup then
         if exist fs%a%b:\EFI\BOOT\startup.nsh then
           fs%a%b:
           cd \EFI\BOOT
           if exist %file% then
             dmpstore -l %file%
             rm %file%
           endif
           if %found% == boot then
             goto BREAK
           endif
           set -v found startup
         endif
       endif
     endfor
   endfor
   alias -v macos "echo ^"Missing macOS^""
   :BREAK
   macos
   ver
   ver -s
   ```

   Next, you will need replace the UUID of `E43602C1-8CFF-4F74-AEC7-98E645C7BBEE` in the `startup.nsh` file with the volume UUID shown in the output from the command below.

   ```
   diskutil info / | grep "Volume UUID"
   ```

   Finally, enter the commands below to install the shell and script files to the EFI partition. If the desired EFI partition is not `disk0s1`, then make the appropriate substitutions.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
   mkdir -p /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT
   bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT --label "UEFI Shell"
   mv Shell_Full.efi /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi
   mv startup.nsh /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/.
   dot_clean -m /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT
   diskutil unmount disk0s1
   ```
3. Install `mkcsrfile` command as a bash script.

   Create a file containing the bash script shown below. Save as `mkcsrfile`  in your `Downloads` folder,

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   if [[ $0 != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]]; then
       bash "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
   fi
   trap exit ERR
   main() {
     local "file=/Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/csr.bin"
     local "unmount=no" "value=0" operand data
     if [[ ! -e /Volumes/EFI ]]; then 
       sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
       unmount="yes"
     fi
     for operand in "$@"; do
       value="$((value|($operand)))"
     done
     printf -v value "%08X" "$value"
     echo "Setting to 0x$value"
     data="240000006300730072002d006100630074006900760065002d0063006f00"
     data+="6e0066006900670000001061437c2aabbb4ba880fe41995c9f8207000000"
     data+="04000000${value:6}${value:4:2}${value:2:2}${value::2}"
     xxd -r -p - "$file" <<<"$data"
     if [[ $unmount == yes ]]; then
       sleep 0.1
       diskutil unmount disk0s1
     fi
   }
   main "$@"
   ```

   Next, if the desired EFI partition is not `disk0s1`, then replace the two occurrences of the `disk0s1` identifier in the `mkcsrfile` file with the desired EFI partition identifier.

   Finally, enter the commands below to install the `mkcsrfile` file to the `/usr/local/bin` folder.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   chmod 755 mkcsrfile
   sudo chown root:wheel mkcsrfile
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
   sudo mv mkcsrfile /usr/local/bin/.
   sudo xattr -c /usr/local/bin/mkcsrfile
   ```
4. Change the default to boot from the UEFI shell.

   Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear. Next, hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while selecting to boot from the "UEFI Shell".

   > Note: When you first boot from the UEFI Shell there will be a startup delay. There should be no delay on subsequent boots.

Comment: I just realized that since I have already installed rEFInd, I can switch between different values of SIP that's defined in the configuration file. I can't find any more values that has an explained correspondence, so thank you very much for your table!

Comment: But I have a question: if I want to disable combinations of things, like no fs, no debug, and no dtrace, how would I know what value to use?

Comment: I added more examples. Post a comment, if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

When the `csr-active-config` variable in not defined, then SIP is enabled when booting macOS. You can remove the variable while booted to macOS by entering the command given below.

```
sudo csrutil clear
```

If the command succeeds, the follow message will appear.

```
Successfully cleared System Integrity Protection. Please restart the machine for the changes to take effect.
```

Comment: @Joy Jin, RE: "`csrutil enable --without fs`" --  I believe even if you could set this from a _normal boot_ it would still require a reboot for it to work.

Comment: You could boot to EFI shell that would set `csr-active-config` from a file, then boot macOS.