# Recovery mode not seeing all APFS snapshots

Tags: macos, apfs

I formatted external hard drive as APFS and installed macOS Catalina to “macOS Catalina” partition, Big Sur to “macOS Big Sur (Intel)” partition and Monterey to “macOS Monterey (Intel)” partition.

I created APFS snapshot in macOS Monterey using `tmutil localsnapshot`.

I confirm snapshot is available running `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /`.

When I boot to recovery mode, I am only able to select “macOS Catalina” disk.

How can I restore macOS Monterey APFS snapshot?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow "restoring from a snapshot" - since I restore the macOS and then once the system boots, you choose a source from which to restore. I wonder if you edited in some more details using `diskutil ap list` to show the specific snapshot you hope to restore we could assist further?